# Link two data records with each other in R

Tags: r, merge, compare

I want to link two data records with each other in R. I need to analyze the context between the global CO<sub>2</sub> emissions (one csv data) and the worldwide population (other csv data).

But it is too difficult to put both data records in one section to get one picture with both data records.

Can you help me?

Comment: Could you show a few lines of each csv?

Comment: `?merge`, `?dpyr::left_join`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Hi, i put both datasets in one dataset in "R". „I want to program a linear regression in "R" with CO2 emission as the dependent variable and population growth as the independent variable. Furthermore it should be displayed in a plot afterwards. How can I show you the dataset? it is in my R program